# Notepad++ disable document switcher mouse shortcut

Tags: mouse, notepad++, shortcuts

Notepad++ has this feature where you can right click + mousewheel to scroll between documents.  My problem is that I hit this all the time by accident resulting in minor (yet cumulative) annoyances such as losing my place when I have many documents open.

I disabled Document Switcher but the switching still happens (just without the popup window showing a list).

I also looked into the Shortcut Mapper, but unfortunately this particular functionality is only listed as a keyboard shortcut which is ctrl+tab.  I really just want to remove the mouse shortcut.

v6.5

Comment: I get the same behavior.  Sounds like you need to file a bug report/feature request for this.

Comment: You can achieve this by creating [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) macro, which will block WheelUp and WheelDown when there is right mouse button pressed. AutoHotKey is the right tool for these adjustments, I have created plenty of them without waiting for app authors to implement something.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) macro can help to achieve what you expect:

```
WheelDown::
  GetKeyState state, RButton, P ; get state of right mouse button
  If (state = "U") {            ; U = up
    Send {WheelDown}
  }
  Return

WheelUp::
  GetKeyState state, RButton, P ; get state of right mouse button
  If (state = "U") {            ; U = up
    Send {WheelUp}
  }
  Return
```

I tested it, it works.

If you want to restrict it only to Notepad++, add [#IfWinActive](https://superuser.com/questions/661981/notepad-disable-document-switcher-mouse-shortcut/1248745#1248745) directive

Comment: I am checking in version 7.6.1 of npp and it switches to next / previous document with just mouse wheel left and right. The shortcut mapper doesn't let me delete these shortcuts from npp